# Android Studio Auto XML tag generation

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

If I am in a layout file and I press CMD/CTRL + N, I get an option to choose XML tag or Copyright. When I choose XML tag and from the list select TextView it generates following;

```
<TextView
    layout_width=""
    layout_height=""/>
```

This gives an error as it should be;

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""/>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

Full XML Code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="cc.zahid.cheatsheet.MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Other > layoutResourceFile.xml
```

Have a look here, edit the template as it will auto-complete with android: instead of without

Comment: Couldn't find anything that could fix that issue.

Comment: Updated my question with that :)